# Red5 Recorder video quality increase

Tags: red5

I am new in the flash and I am using the red5 recorder to record video. Camera that i use is imac around 2 megapixel. While i am recording the video its fine and after record done, i save the video in vzaar. While i fetch the video from vzzar then the video is badly pixelated. How can i make the video fine?

```
cam.setQuality(0,90);
```

I keep this code in the as file. But this didn't work.

How can i improve the quality of video can you please suggest?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `set.Camera(0,100)`... is this action script code? if yes it is wrong

Comment: @fmodos can you please suggest me how can i increse quality, i think i am doing wrong. :(

Comment: I posted a code example

Answer (score 2):

You can read the documentation of the class [Camera](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000137.html) for a better understanding of the properties.

Anyway here is a code suggestion to get the best webcam quality:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera()
//width, height of the video you are recording and fps(frame per seconds)
camera.setMode(400, 400, 15);
//set the bandwith to 0 which means that it will use all it can, 
//and the quality to 100 which is the best quality it can get
camera.setQuality(0, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This article will help you to get the better video quality with red5 and flash

http://www.technogumbo.com/tutorials/Recording-Decent-Quality-Video-And-Audio-With-Flash-and-Red5/index.php

Comment: @Pus its working man. check your firewall.

Note: Think twice before giving -ve votes..

Comment: that link was not working while i open and i didnot make any negative votes, please check the link twice while giving answer.

Comment: @SriHarish yea this time the page is loading but at july 22 it was not opening. so i write the comment..